# Why can't pgrep find this process?

Tags: linux, bash, ps, grep

If I execute the following, which is just a long command that will wait forever

```
grep 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa abcd'
```

then `pgrep -f` can't find the process, if I search for `abcd` which is contained in the last segment of the long command.

`ps auxww|grep abcd` finds the process, but I can't use it in a script, as it also finds the `grep` process self.

If you remove just one `a` then `pgrep -f abcd` can find the process, but I have very long command with arguments, so I have run into this `pgrep` limitation.

**Question**

What is the correct way to check for such process based on the unique string `abcd`?

Comment: When data is sent to the `mbuffer` process it will exit when the data stream ends.

Comment: So how do you know process is still running? Did you check `top` command? btw why downvote to this question? +1

Comment: The purpose of the long command is to receive data over port 8023. In my script do I have this long receiver command and also the sending command. Even though the sending command exit, it can still take a little while before the receiving commands exits, so that is why I want to check for `abcd`. If I find it, then I will wait a second, check again, and only continue when I don't see `abcd` in the process list.

Comment: So even `top` is not showing this process in the list?

Comment: I can't see it, but then again it doesn't take any cpu when no data is sent to it. I have updated the OP, so now it can be reproduced on my Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67829/discussion-between-jasmine-lognnes-and-anubhava).

Comment: `pgrep` is in general the solution you desire. However, It's easier sometimes to get the result in `ps auxww`'s format, rather than just PID (as returned by pgrep). Use `ps auxww|grep [a]bcd` instead of `ps auxww|grep abcd`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your edited command is found by either of these commands:

```
pgrep -f abcd
```

or even:

```
ps uxww | grep '[a]bcd'
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me try that...

```
$ grep 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa abcd'
```

Now in another terminal window:

```
$ pgrep grep
1842
```

Found it, or at least some `grep` process:

```
$ ps -f $(pgrep grep)
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501  1842  1836   0  8:59AM ttys004    0:00.00 grep aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa abcd
```

Yup, that was the process found.

Let's try this:

```
$ pgrep -f 'abcd'
1842
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: Good point. I thought I were using `procps-ng` but I wasn't. So that's why it didn't work for me. I have to upgrade =)